# PDFBox - Refreshing nested PDComboBox from Java

Tags: java, combobox, pdfbox

I'm new using PDFBox and need some help.

I have searched on the internet, but I didn't find anything and have tried plenty of things.

I have to parse from a PDF file in order to fill out some fields from Java and export it filled out again, taking data from the database. I have several nested combo boxes and when I put the value in the first one, it shows the correct text for the value, but the problem arrives when I put the value in the nested combo box, it shows the value instead of the text, it doesn't refresh the value's list depend on the first combo box.

This problem doesn't happen if you edit the PDF file from a PDF editor.

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream parseToSmartPdf(final File file, final Map<String, String> pdfContentMap) {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
    try {
        final InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        final PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(inputStream.readAllBytes());
        inputStream.close();
        final PDAcroForm pdfAcroForm = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
        if (Objects.isNull(pdfAcroForm)) {
            throw new FileEmptyException();
        }

        for (final Map.Entry<String, String> entry : new TreeMap<>(pdfContentMap).entrySet()) {
            final String key = entry.getKey();
            final String value = entry.getValue();
            final PDField field = pdfAcroForm.getField(key);
            if ("Tx".equals(field.getFieldType())) {
                field.setValue(value);
            } else if ("Ch".equals(field.getFieldType())) {
                if (field instanceof PDComboBox) {
                    final PDComboBox pdComboBox = (PDComboBox) field;
                    pdComboBox.setValue(value);
                }
            }
        }
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        pdfDocument.save(baos);
        pdfDocument.close();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new FileProcessingException();
    }
    return baos;
}
```

Edited:

PDFBox version: 2.0.0 (I tried with the latest version too: 2.0.21)

A link to the PDF file that I'm using to test.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vKslaheP7ADlCca75X1jjd2f8Cca7AzU/view?usp=sharing

Conflicting fields:

- When and where -> World region <-> State/area
- Aircraft information ->
  Manufacturer <-> Model
- Flight details -> Last departure point ->
  Country <-> ICAO code
- Flight details -> Planned destination ->
  Country <-> ICAO code

Thanks for the support beforehand.

Comment: Please share the file and tell the pdfbox version.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thanks, I have already updated the post:

Comment: You should always try with the latest version before even asking a question. Your link requests a login, this is not ok. Be aware that PDFBox does not support relationships between fields, this is javascript. PDFBox sees each field individually. (I'm not sure if that was your question or not) There is also no such thing as "nested" combobox. I suspect that is a visual thing.

Comment: Hi again @TilmanHausherr and thank you. I tried with the latest version, but the problem continues. Sorry, perhaps I explained wrong and have fixed the link too. I think that I have to try the way to run the trigger that happens when I select an option of the first combo box, in the PDF editor, in order to refresh the options list of the second combo box.

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear. The field "T1S5_E24-1/4-1_DT12_A167-1/L1" (Last departure point) has Javascript which can be found by using PDFDebugger and opening "Root/AcroForm/Fields/[5617]/Kids/[0]/AA/Bl/JS" (in the "internal structure" view). You would have to replicate that logic :-(

Comment: Thanks, @TilmanHausherr, it works! I could check the name that those scripts use to call the component where get options and values to load the another combo box and I discovered that they have name that we can compose with data from our database then I replicated that logic with methods of PDFBox to load several combo box dinamically. =)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @TilmanHausherr for your support.

Using PDFDebugger you can see that PDF files have an internal combo box for each option of the "parent" combo box where you can take option-value list to load the "nested" combo box.

1. Open the PDF file with PDFDebugger (you need to download the jar of PDFBox app):

   java -jar pdfbox-app-x.x.x.jar PDFDebugger <pdf_file_name>
2. Activate the following option to show PDF content and check them easier: "View -> Show Internal Structure"
3. In the components tree go to "Root -> AcroForm -> Fields" where you can see all the components and their attributes, options, values, etc.

When you know the respective names you can load the "nested" combo box with the following code:

```
final PDField optionsValuesField = pdComboBox.getAcroForm().getField("optionsValuesFieldName");
final PDComboBox optionsValuesPdComboBox = (PDComboBox) optionsValuesField;

final PDField nestedPdComboBoxField = pdComboBox.getAcroForm().getField("nestedPdComboBoxName");
final PDComboBox nestedPdComboBox = (PDComboBox) nestedPdComboBoxField;

nestedPdComboBox.setOptions(optionsValuesPdComboBox.getOptionsExportValues(), optionsValuesPdComboBox.getOptionsDisplayValues());
```

Comment: You can also hover with the mouse in the page view over a field and the name will appear in the status line.